# Android package 'android.bluetooth.le' in Support library

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-bluetooth

In final Android 5.0 APIs, We see that android.bluetooth.le package requires API level 21. This is as expected. Though this is not added as part of support libraries. This means that to use 'le' package we will have to generate 2 separate APKs, one for level 21 and other for api levels below 21.

Should we expect android.bluetooth.le package to be added into any of support libraries?